# iPhone submission - The binary you uploaded was invalid

Tags: iphone, binary, appstore-approval

Having gone through all the steps of submitting my app to the iStore by the book (and other manuals around), I get a 'not so funny' response after uploading my binary:

'The binary you uploaded was invalid. Fat binaries require a MinimumOSVersion of at least 3.0'

Now, I set the device deplyment to be 2.2.1 and the Base SDK the same.   My build SDK is 3.0 and I'm pretty sure I do not use anything which is in 3.0 but not in the 2.2.1 API (I built and ran on both and tested).

It might be nothing, or not - I do use XML parsing and some XML files in my application, again, I'm not even sure that it is connected ot the problem.

If you have any experience with that or have a clue it's be great,

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Info.plist` of the binary that is produced. The file should have the following setting somewhere in it:

```
MinimumOSVersion XYZ
```

...where `XYZ` is the Deployment Target OS version you are trying to build for.

I have noticed in my own binaries that this line does *not* exist for binaries built for the iPhone Simulator. Given that, my suspicion is that you are trying to upload a binary built for the simulator instead of the device. Try changing the Active SDK to "iPhone Device 2.2.1" and submitting *that* binary to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was due to me zipping the file up (or trying to upload it) from a PC. I used 'compress' on the mac and uploaded using firefox for mac os and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This window becomes visible upon clicking on the root project name in the Xcode directory /groups tree, where you can change the:

! [Deployment Target OS 8.1 and SDK declarations](http://cl.ly/image/0V1N1f1J203t/Image%202015-03-14%20at%205.45.33%20AM.png)

Also, under the General tab is the **Asset Catalog** where the Icon migration and Launch screen file conversion takes place.